# Add ngRoute to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am using angularjs with yeoman. I am trying to add ngRoute to my project. I've install it with bower

> "angular-route": "~1.4.1",

and when I try to load it in app.js I get this error

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch','ngRoute'])
```

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

Comment: Did you include script tag in HTML?

Comment: You need to include the script in your HTML (with all your other scripts)

Comment: I assume that the Script has not been added to HTML. Moreover, you arre planning to use ngRoute with ui-router ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that in addition to including angular.js you also include:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/angular-route.js"></script>`

See [ngRoute API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) for installation instructions.

Answer (score 5):

you need to refer the angular-route.js, pls find the cdn link as follows

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

also you can get the latest version cdn for angular in following link
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/1.4.0